# converting variables to dictionaries, Making variable string as value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have about 50 urls named
url1.....url50
I want to make a dictionary of these variables
for example:

```
url1 = "https://example1.com"
url2 = "https://example2.com"
url3 = "https://example3.com"
```

.
.
I tried this::

```
all_urls = {}
a= 'url'

for i in range(1,51):

    all_urls[a+str(i)] = a+str(i)
```

For this I get the keys right but how can I get variables as the value.

Output:

```
{'url1': 'url1',
 'url10': 'url10',
 'url11': 'url11',
 'url12': 'url12',
 'url13': 'url13',
 'url14': 'url14',
 'url2': 'url2',
 'url3': 'url3',
 'url4': 'url4',
 'url5': 'url5',
 'url6': 'url6',
 'url7': 'url7',
 'url8': 'url8',
 'url9': 'url9'
```

Desired output:

```
'url1' : 'https://example.com'
'url2' : 'https://example.org'
'url3' : 'https://example.com'


and so on..
```

Comment: Where are the actual URLS stored?

Comment: in a variable named url1,url2,url3....

Comment: why are you storing them in different objects? store them in a separate `dict` from beginning

Comment: these are just a copy of a file that has been provided, there are more than 500, that would take a lot of time

Comment: "there are more than 500, that would take a lot of time" - that is what search and replace in text editors is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `globals` here.

**Ex:**

```
url1 = "https://example1.com"
url2 = "https://example2.com"
url3 = "https://example3.com"

all_urls = {}
a= 'url'

for i in range(1,4):
    all_urls[a+str(i)] = globals()[a+str(i)]
print(all_urls)
```

**Output:**

```
{'url1': 'https://example1.com', 'url3': 'https://example3.com', 'url2': 'https://example2.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `locals()`

```
>>> url1 = "https://example1.com"
>>> url2 = "https://example2.com"
>>> url3 = "https://example3.com"
>>> 
>>> {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if k.startswith('url')}
{'url3': 'https://example3.com', 'url1': 'https://example1.com', 'url2': 'https://example2.com'}
```